# Agregar Nuevos Valores a Dataframe de acuerdo a predicciones

Tags: python, pandas, predicción

Tengo el siguiente dataframe llamado "ultimosDias":

```
                    Unidades
Fecha   
2021-06-01 00:00:00    3
2021-06-01 01:00:00    4
2021-06-01 02:00:00    1
2021-06-01 03:00:00    2
2021-06-01 04:00:00    8
2021-06-01 05:00:00    9
2021-06-01 06:00:00    3
2021-06-01 07:00:00    5
2021-06-01 08:00:00    7
2021-06-01 09:00:00    8
```

Quiero integrar a mi dataframe las predicciones de mi modelo, por lo cual tengo la siguiente función para agregar los nuevos valores a partir de la ultima fila + 1 del dataframe:

```
def agregarNuevoValor(ultimosDias,nuevoValor):
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(ultimosDias)):
        ultimosDias[i] = ultimosDias[i+1]
    ultimosDias[ultimosDias.iloc[-1]]=nuevoValor
    return ultimosDias
```

Quiero agregar los resultados de mi pronostico para los proximos 30 dias:

```
steps = 24*20
resultados=[]
for i in range(7):
    pred = forecaster.predict(steps=steps)
    resultados.append(pred)
    print(predictions)
    ultimosDias=agregarNuevoValor(ultimosDias,pred)
```

El error que me da es `KeyError: 1` al aplicar la función `ultimosDias=agregarNuevoValor(ultimosDias,predictions)` en la linea de la función `ultimosDias[i] = ultimosDias[i+1]`

Pueda que tenga un error de concepto básico de aplicar el aumento `i+1` o deba considera aplicar un shape, pero requiero de su apoyo para saber que opcion sería la mas optima para poder agregar los nuevos valores a mi dataframe original.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas sobreescribiendo en la fila 0, por lo que la estas eliminando. Con el código `agregarNuevoValor` estas subiendo cada fila 1 hacia arriba, pandas ya puede hacerlo con `.shift(-1)`. Para agregar datos puedes hacerlo con `.append()` o `.concat()` o `pd.DataFrame([[df1],[df2]])`.
La respuesta como tal depende del formato de los datos que quieres adjuntarle al DataFrame, y si quieres conservar los 30 más recientes (como haces en el intento) o ir acumulando filas hacia abajo.

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa Creo que concatenando podría ser solución pero aclárame algo, ¿Cómo se concatenan para que empieza a registrar a partir de la última fila + 1, es decir; que siga el conteo de fecha y hora del dataframe original para cada predicción en el día +1?

Comment: concat es mejor cuando tienes dos dataframe. ambos con las fechas ya puestas. Te sirve si del modelo salen todos los 30 datos a la vez con las fechas respectivas, automáticamente lo pone debajo del último dato y en caso de que no esten ordenados por fecha aun puedes aplicar ordenar (`.sort()`).
Si es un dato a la vez y el tiempo es fijo (1 hora), conviene hacerlo manualmente con `.at` (específico para 1 solo dato a la vez) o `.loc` (1 o más datos a la vez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude dar con la solución que fue la siguiente:

Aplique `pd.date-range` para crear una nueva columna de fechas en el dataframe creado "proxMes" y reflejar los pronósticos. La función aplicada `proxMes['FHBitacora'] = pd.date_range(start= ultimosDias.index[-1], periods=len(ultimosDias),  freq="H")` toma como inicio el último día del dataframe original "ultimosDias" para anexarle las horas y días posteriores basado en la longitud del dataframe original, la cual une los resultados de los pronosticos a partir del día + 1 de la ultima fecha del dataframe origina "ultimosDias".

Por último, lo que hice fue aplicar `apend`para agregar el dataframe construido con los pronósticos "proxMes" al dataframe original "ultimosDias" `ultimosDias.append(proxMes)`, obteniendo los resultados esperados.

No se si será la solución más optima pero me es totalmente funcional y cumple con la expectativas de mi proyecto.

Gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla de agregar datos a tu *DataFrame* es usando el método `loc` donde solo tendremos que especificar el nuevo índice (en tu df se ve que `Fechas` es el índice). Por lo que quedaría así.

```py
df.loc["2021-06-02 04:00:00"] = [10] #el nuevo valor
```

Adaptandolo a tu función:

```py
def agregarPrediccion(df, values):
    for i in range(len(values)):
        ultimo = datetime.strptime(df.iloc[-1].name, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        #lo agregamos como string por que sino en la proxima iteracións nos dará error
        df.loc[f"{ultimo+timedelta(days=1)}"] = values[i] 
    return df
```

Esta función recibe un dataframe y una lista de todos los valores predichos, entonces, en cada iteración se obtiene el último valor del *DataFrame* y se convierte a tipo datetime y se agrega 1 día con `timedelta(days=1)`, finalmente retorna el *DataFrame* con todos los valores añadidos

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta pero no entendí cuando comentas que mi modelo genera una sola predicción cuando más bien me genera 30 valores predictivos en la lista llamada resultados. Esos resultados de esa lista, los quiero anexar al día +1 de mi ultimo dato histórico en el dataframe. Si pudieras aclararme como agregar esa lista de resultados a partir del final del dataframe, te lo agradeceré... Mi solución por ahora es pensar en concatenar la lista de resultados al dataframe original como me lo recomiendan en un comentario. Quiero que siga agregando días y horas consecutivos.

Comment: tu modelo te genera los 30 días de *"golpe"* o es un ciclo que va prediciendo día a día?

Comment: De golpe de acuerdo los pasos o steps que le digo a mi modelo que prediga

Comment: te devuelve el `dia` junto  al `valor` o solo el valor?

Comment: Solo el valor...Los índices son 0, 1, 2... etc

Comment: ultima pregunta, con esto ya puedo editar la respuesta, ¿Los índices de tu dataframe son las fechas o son numeros 1,2,3...?

Comment: Los índices de mi dataframe original son las fechas, justo es a la que quiero agregar los valores a partir del ultimo índice, que en este caso es una fecha, la cual requiero que los pronósticos vengan a acompañados del índice final + 1.

Comment: He editado la respuesta, avísame si te sirve o tienes errores

Comment: Con tu función, igualmente debo declarar un valor inicial?

Comment: como valor inicial? tu no necesitas hacer nada, solo pasarle el dataframe y los datos a agregar